# How can use crystal report in WCF services

Tags: wcf, crystal-reports-2010

I am working on WCF web services  and  SQL server 2012.  I have facing  problem of below mention WCF service namely `Print_Invoice` can not work after published  it on server IIS, but it  can be run on locally successful please how I can solve this problem.

```
[WebMethod]
     [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
     public string Print_Invoice(int Duty_Slip_Id)
     {
         try
         {
             List<Common.DTO.InvoiceDTO>data=new List<InvoiceDTO>();
             ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
             using (T_FleetEntities e = new T_FleetEntities())
             {
                 var v = e.Print_Invoice(Duty_Slip_Id);
                 if (v != null)
                 {
                     v.ToList().ForEach(o => data.Add(new Common.DTO.InvoiceDTO()
                     {
                        PNR_No = o.PRN_NO == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : (string)o.PRN_NO,
                         Inv_Date = Convert.ToString(o.Inv_Date.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Inv_Date.ToString()),
                         Date_In = Convert.ToString(o.Date_In.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Date_In.ToString()),
                         Date_Out = Convert.ToString(o.Date_Out.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Date_Out.ToString()),
                         Time_Out = Convert.ToString(o.Time_Out.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Time_Out.ToString()),
                         Tot_Days = Convert.ToString(o.Tot_Days.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Tot_Days.ToString()),
                         Time_In = Convert.ToString(o.Time_In.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Time_In.ToString()),
                         Km_In = Convert.ToString(o.Km_In.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Km_In.ToString()),
                         Km_Out = Convert.ToString(o.Km_Out.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Km_Out.ToString()),
                         Tot_Hrs = Convert.ToString(o.Tot_Hrs.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Tot_Hrs.ToString()),
                         Tot_Km = Convert.ToString(o.Tot_Km.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Tot_Km.ToString()),
                         Extra_Hr_Amt = Convert.ToString(o.Extra_Hr_Amt.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Extra_Hr_Amt.ToString()),
                         Extra_Km_Amt = Convert.ToString(o.Extra_Km_Amt.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Extra_Km_Amt.ToString()),
                         Night_Allow = Convert.ToString(o.Night_Allow.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Night_Allow.ToString()),
                         Out_Stn_Allow = Convert.ToString(o.Out_Stn_Allow.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Out_Stn_Allow.ToString()),
                         Pkg_Id = Convert.ToString(o.Pkg_Id.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Pkg_Id.ToString()),
                         Rate = Convert.ToString(o.Basic_Rate.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Basic_Rate.ToString()),
                         //Comp_Id = Convert.ToString(o.com.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Comp_Id.ToString()),
                         Extra_Hr = Convert.ToString(o.Extra_Hr.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Extra_Hr.ToString()),
                         Extra_Km = Convert.ToString(o.Extra_Km.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Extra_Km.ToString()),
                         //F_Cat_Id = Convert.ToString(o.F_Cat_Id.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.F_Cat_Id.ToString()),
                         //F_Type_Id = Convert.ToString(o.F_Type_Id.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.F_Type_Id.ToString()),
                         //Feedback = Convert.ToString(o.Feedback.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Feedback.ToString()),
                         Gross_Amt = Convert.ToString(o.Gross_Amt.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Gross_Amt.ToString()),
                         Inter_State_Tax = Convert.ToString(o.Inter_State_Tax.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Inter_State_Tax.ToString()),
                         //Inv_Status = Convert.ToString(o.Inv_Status.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Inv_Status.ToString()),
                         Other_Rec = Convert.ToString(o.Other_Rec.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Other_Rec.ToString()),
                         Parking = Convert.ToString(o.Parking.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Parking.ToString()),
                         Serv_Tax_Amt = Convert.ToString(o.Serv_Tax_Amt.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Serv_Tax_Amt.ToString()),
                         Toll = Convert.ToString(o.Toll.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Toll.ToString()),
                         Total_Amt = Convert.ToString(o.Total_Amt.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Total_Amt.ToString()),
                         Comp_Nm = Convert.ToString(o.Comp_Nm.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Comp_Nm.ToString()),
                         Company_Email = Convert.ToString(o.Company_Email.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Company_Email.ToString()),
                         Rep_Guest = Convert.ToString(o.Rep_Guest.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Rep_Guest.ToString()),
                         Company_Addr = Convert.ToString(o.Company_Addr.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Company_Addr.ToString()),
                         Company_Nm = Convert.ToString(o.Company_Nm.ToString() == (object)DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : o.Company_Nm.ToString())
                      }));
                }
              string strReportPath;
             strReportPath =HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("PrintInvoice.rpt");
             rd.Load(Path.Combine(strReportPath));
             rd.SetDataSource(data);
             rd.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("files/Invoice.pdf"));

            //Stream strem  =rd.ExportToStream( CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
            //strem.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            // File(strem, "application/pdf", "files/Invoice.pdf");
         }

             string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("files/Invoice.pdf");
             return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(path);

       }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {

             return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ex);
             throw;

         }

     }
```

Comment: What happens when you publish it?  Do you get an error?

Comment: *can not work after published it on server IIS* - Though we are powerful, StackOverflow has not yet evolved the power to read minds. We are working on it, but until then you will have to actually copy and paste your exception into your post.